# Understanding the resource file of a program(Win32)

Tags: winapi

Say i have a simple Win32 program with a menu, and all syntax is correct. Here is the resource file:

```
#define IDR_MYMENU                      101
#define IDI_MYICON                      102
#define ID_FILE_EXIT                    40001
#define ID_STUFF_GO                     40002
#define ID_STUFF_GOSOMEWHEREELSE        40003
```

Im a little confused on the constants declared, could i use any ol number to represent each option? such as:

```
#define IDR_MYMENU                      23
#define IDI_MYICON                      412
#define ID_FILE_EXIT                    40071
#define ID_STUFF_GO                     40892
#define ID_STUFF_GOSOMEWHEREELSE        64982
```

or is there something behind those specific numbers? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any valid 16-bit unsigned integer value (i.e <= 65535). They are used to uniquely identify a resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use most any number. However, I have found that on WinCE some menu item identifiers can be reserved for special system actions. It is best to avoid those below 100.